# What is Bitcoin Gold?

Tags: blockchain-fork, bitcoin-gold

There have been a lot of discussions about [bitcoin-gold](/questions/tagged/bitcoin-gold). What is it? I couldn't find an official website or something?

Answer (score 2):

Bitcoin Gold is a new hard fork planned by Jack Liao (CEO of LightningASIC), that will happen on October 25. It's main aim is to decentralize mining by changing the Proof-of-Work algorithm to ZCash's [Equihash algorithm](https://z.cash/blog/why-equihash.html), and they promise it'll switch to a different PoW when ASICs are launched.

Its addresses will start with `G` (P2PKH) or `A` (P2SH), and it has replay protection. <sub><sub><sub>[Source](https://bitcoingold.org/bitcoin-gold-daily-dev-update-26-10-2017/)</sub></sub></sub>

The official website is [bitcoingold.org](https://bitcoingold.org)

Also These can be used to contact them:

- https://github.com/BTCGPU/BTCGPU
- https://twitter.com/btcgpu